# SmartOS/illumos/OpenSolaris ntp stuck in INIT & server is drifting

Tags: opensolaris, ntpd

(I asked the same question on SmartOS ML but no luck)

I noticed that one of my servers was off several minutes so I digged into my ntp and noticed that something seems wrong:

```
ntpq -c peers
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset jitter
 beyond.work.de  .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000  0.000
 ntp1.m-online.n .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000  0.000
```

Looks like it never gets over the "INIT" phase for some reason, I assume that should be a different state in there?

In the log I see (after a restart of ntp):

```
 6 Aug 14:10:47 ntpd[53519]: ntpd exiting on signal 15 (Terminated)
 6 Aug 14:10:47 ntpd[53519]: 213.238.32.2 local addr 212.12.41.94 -> <null>
 6 Aug 14:10:47 ntpd[53519]: 144.76.43.40 local addr 212.12.41.94 -> <null>
 6 Aug 14:10:47 ntpd[55024]: Listen and drop on 0 v6wildcard [::]:123
 6 Aug 14:10:47 ntpd[55024]: Listen and drop on 1 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
 6 Aug 14:10:47 ntpd[55024]: Listen normally on 2 lo0 [::1]:123
 6 Aug 14:10:47 ntpd[55024]: Listen normally on 3 lo0 127.0.0.1:123
 6 Aug 14:10:47 ntpd[55024]: Listen normally on 4 igb0 212.12.41.94:123
 6 Aug 14:10:47 ntpd[55024]: Listening on routing socket on fd #53 for interface updates
 6 Aug 14:10:47 ntpd[55024]: kernel reports TIME_ERROR: 0x41: Clock Unsynchronized
 6 Aug 14:10:47 ntpd[55024]: kernel reports TIME_ERROR: 0x41: Clock Unsynchronized
```

That's almost 1 day ago and I see no other messages.

my ntp.conf:

```
driftfile /var/ntp/ntp.drift
logfile /var/log/ntp.log

# Ignore all network traffic by default
restrict default ignore
restrict -6 default ignore

# Allow localhost to manage ntpd
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict -6 ::1

# Allow servers to reply to our queries
restrict source nomodify noquery notrap

# Allow connections from trusted NTP servers
restrict pool.ntp.org mask 255.255.255.255 nomodify notrap noquery
restrict 213.238.32.2 mask 255.255.255.255 nomodify notrap noquery

# Time Servers
server 213.238.32.2 burst iburst minpoll 4
server pool.ntp.org iburst
```

I have no firewall rules in place so I'm really not sure what is going on here. Also ntpdate seems to be able to connect to servers, so the biggest diff is now fixed. But I assume I will drift again soon that way.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did your ISP put firewall rules in place? Specifically, did something start blocking "inbound" NTP queries? The "peer to peer" NTP mode that ntpd uses is easy to accidentally block that way.

Comment: One of the servers is within the ISP so I doubt it. And wouldn't I not be able to do ntpdate if that would be the case?